# IOS m3u8 wrong video quality using vimeo pro

Tags: http-live-streaming, vimeo-api, vimeo-ios

Using a vimeo pro account for iOS m3u8 streaming using AVPlayer on iPad, it always selects SD stream on all videos, even when I'm on 4G network which provides speed around 16Mbps. YouTube app selects the HD stream always on the same network. I'm certain HD will have no problems playing on this bandwidth. Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: The m3u8 file is just a textfile. Can you open it and tell me what resolutions are supported? If you see HD in there, I believe this is out of our hands, and is a decision made by AVPlayer. Feel free to contact Vimeo at vimeo.com/help/contact in either case.

Comment: @Dashron Hi, 960x540, 1280x720, 1920x1080, it always selects 960x540. However, this is not the case when a google DFP m3u8 ad is being played, the only difference is in between the bitrate between the two m3u8, for ex the bandwidth tag for 1280x720 in case of m3u8 supplied by google DFP is much less than that provided by vimeo, nonetheless DFP video plays just fine, but considering 16Mbps speed, bandwidth should not be a problem

Comment: Can you send us some examples via the vimeo.com/help/contact ? We may be able to help further from there, but it sounds like the higher bitrate is causing the player to select a lower quality resolution.